# Confusion regarding java's multiple inheritance.Please read below

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

Well this is allowed in java

```
ClassA extends ClassB implements InterfaceA
```

and also

```
InterfaceA extends IntefaceB , InterfaceC
```

Well if these arenot multiple inheritance then what are they?

UPDATE

Well I happened to phrase the question in a wrong way. My original question was why doesn't java support multiple inheritance.

Well what I really want to know is:

if more than one interface can be extended by an interface, or a class can extend one class and implement an interface, then why can't those be called multiple inheritance?

Comment: Because multiple inheritance is incredibly complicated and inefficient.

Comment: This is most certainly not a duplicate of the question linked, the question isn't "why doesn't Java support multiple inheritance", it's "why, given the ability to extend multiple interfaces, *do we say* that Java doesn't support multiple inheritance?"  However, duffymo's answer under that question can be helpful.

Comment: @MarkPeters Yes thats what i meant.But it was my bad.Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between an interface and a regular class is that you cannot specify implementation in an interface. To be more clear, you can only specify methods, but not implement them. If you want to have multiple inheritance then you have to `implement` multiple interface. Java does not support multiple inheritance due to the below reasons.

Also to note that **Interfaces are about subtyping and polymorphism, whereas, inheriting methods is about code reuse.**

From [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2002-07/02-qa-0719-multinheritance.html):

> The reasons for omitting multiple inheritance from the Java language
>   mostly stem from the "simple, object oriented, and familiar" goal. As
>   a simple language, Java's creators wanted a language that most
>   developers could grasp without extensive training. To that end, they
>   worked to make the language as similar to C++ as possible (familiar)
>   without carrying over C++'s unnecessary complexity (simple).
>
> In the designers' opinion, multiple inheritance causes more problems
>   and confusion than it solves. So they cut multiple inheritance from
>   the language (just as they cut operator overloading). The designers'
>   extensive C++ experience taught them that multiple inheritance just
>   wasn't worth the headache.

You can find this interesting [article](http://javapapers.com/core-java/why-multiple-inheritance-is-not-supported-in-java/) on the same:-

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Java *does* support multiple inheritance; just take note that the support is very constrained: you can only inherit more than one *interface*. That is why you have heard that Java is single-inheritance: it is single *class* inheritance.

NB Java 8 will push its design even closer to multiple inheritance: `interface` will be allowed to define method implementations and a class will indeed inherit *implementation* from multiple parents. The diamond problem will be efficiencly solved by requiring the class having the conflict override the method. Within that override, the child class will be able to refer to each supertype implementation individually.

Thus, as of version 8, Java can be said to almost posses full multiple inheritance of implementation, just with *manual resolution of conflicts*, unlike C++ and other languages, which specify a formula for how the compiler will automatically resolve them.

Comment: +1, and good for mentioning Java 8.  A bit of a refinement though: when the diamond situation occurs, the interface/class that inherits multiple default implementations can provide a new method definition to resolve the compile error.  In its simplest case it can just delegate to one of the 2+ interfaces that define it.

Comment: I've been doing some experimental development of a complex multiple inheritance hierarchy using interfaces and it really opens up a new world. For me, single inheritance is dead. I'd rather have no inheritance than single inheritance. It just never works for me. With Interfaces and default methods I can get the elegant designs I always wanted but could never build in Java. In Javascript you can get multiple inheritance to work but it takes effort. If you want you can try my JS library [mics](https://mics.js.org) to help you with it.

Answer (score 2):

As Inheritance defined as:

> inheriting attributes and behavior from pre-existing classes called base classes, superclasses, or parent classes

Inheritance is to take some **implementation** from parent class. If a class inherit a class there must be some methods and attributes that child class inherited from base class.

But implementing an interface is not in general add some attributes or behavior.So when a class implements multiple interfaces there is no additional implementation comes from interfaces Or in other words we can say a class cannot inherit implementation from two different sources.

Reason why Multiple Inheritance is not allowed.

(reference wikipedia)

### [Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)

The "diamond problem" (sometimes referred to as the "deadly diamond of death") is an ambiguity that arises when two classes B and C inherit from A, and class D inherits from both B and C. If there is a method in A that B and/or C has overridden, and D does not override it, then which version of the method does D inherit: that of B, or that of C?

For example, in the context of GUI software development, a class Button may inherit from both classes Rectangle (for appearance) and Clickable (for functionality/input handling), and classes Rectangle and Clickable both inherit from the Object class. Now if the equals method is called for a Button object and there is no such method in the Button class but there is an overridden equals method in Rectangle or Clickable (or both), which method should be eventually called?

It is called the "diamond problem" because of the shape of the class inheritance diagram in this situation. In this article, class A is at the top, both B and C separately beneath it, and D joins the two together at the bottom to form a diamond shape.

> [image]

Comment: I think you're answering the question title but not the question itself.  I think the question is "if classes or interfaces can implement/extend multiple interfaces, how is that not considered multiple inheritance"?

Answer (score 1):

Java has no support for multiple inheritance. To explain the first example:

```
ClassA extends ClassB implements InterfaceA
```

In here, `ClassA` is extending a single class, and implementing a single interface. Whereas in the second case:

```
InterfaceA extends IntefaceB, InterfaceC
```

An interface is declared to extend from two other interfaces, you can think of this as "adding" all the methods from the extended interfaces, but it's not really multiple inheritance, the class that implements `InterfaceA` will have to provide implementations for all the methods defined in `InterfaceA`, `InterfaceB` *and* `InterfaceC`.

Comment: The concept just needs to be qualified, as Mark did in the comment above.

Comment: @MarkPeters for me, inheritance is about _reusing_ behaviour. An interface extending from another interface is simply adding method declarations, but no behaviour is being reused by the simple fact that interfaces don't have method implementations (although Java 8 is going to change this a bit, so let's stick to Java 7 for now)

Comment: We should at least giva a nod of respect to the meaning of the term "inherit" as used in the JLS. Interface methods *are* inherited.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I realized my comment would be confusing until I could find a link to describe the difference between type and implementation inheritance, and deleted my comment before you guys posted.  I do think that implementing interfaces is a kind of inheritance, but not the kind of inheritance they're talking about when they say "Java does not support multiple inheritance."

Comment: @MarkPeters Truth be told, it is more salient to differentiate *interface inheritance* from *class inheritance* because the split between type/implementation inheritance will be much blurred as of Java 8.